# How can I autoload classes with composer where the filenames are suffixed with .class.php?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I am using `composer` autoloader for my classes too, but my problem is that files with my classes follow the pattern `ClassName.class.php` and `composer` can load files only with `.php` extension.

Is there any way how to define file pattern in `composer.json`? I was checking `classmap`, but it doesn't support patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classmap autoloading should be your friend, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap.

Just specify the path to wherever you've got your files, let's say when your files reside in `src`, for example, `src/Foo/Bar.class.php`, then update your `composer.json` like this

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "src/"
        ]
    }
}
```

You will need to regenerate the classmap, though, every time you add a new file:

```
$ composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, I just used `classmap` wrong way.